# Triggering ObjectOutputStream write using ActionListener

Tags: java, sockets, actionlistener, objectoutputstream

So basically, I am working on a project that requires me to send an array that gets filled with Strings via a GUI to a server. Once the array is filled, I want an "Enter" button to send that array to the server through the socket. The problem is, I don't know how I could make an actionListener that could do that in this scenario.

This is the connection on the client socket:

```
public class Client {
    public Client() {
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
            Socket client = new Socket(addr, 10000);

            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

            String svResponse;

            while (true) {
                oout.writeObject(sequence);
                oout.flush();

                InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                ArrayList<String> sequenceServ = (ArrayList<String>) oin.readObject();
                System.out.println(sequenceServ.toString());

                InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
                svResponse = buffReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(svResponse);
            }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        }
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to have a button on my GUI that would trigger something like `oout.writeObject(sequence);`

Please feel free to tell me if anything seems unclear as I am aware that the explanation isn't really well done since I'm not sure how to formulate it myself.

Comment: Step 1) Implement an ActionListener on some GUI - have you done that?

Comment: Yes, the issue here is that I simply can't find a way to implement an ActionListener that could execute the ```writeObject()``` method outside of the Client socket class since. The only thing I know how to implement an ActionListener on is a GUI and what I'm looking for in this case is the other way around.

Comment: So the GUI is not the above code?  Make a method on Client that does the writing.